# If Orientation changes on android device my app language is changing by default language. Help me

Tags: android, multilingual

If I change my device orientation my app language also changed as default language on oreo+ version. Language not changing on 8+. Help me.

Comment: This much information is not enough to help you out!

Comment: private static boolean updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        return true;
    }

Comment: This is my localeutils class. I have updated my language on my application class.

Comment: [Edit your question and post additional information,  don't post that in comment section.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56442090/edit)

Answer (score 2):

You should call your method

```
updateResources(Context context, String language)
```

in your activity or fragment's onResume()

The onResume() method is called when screen orientation changes, hence your texts will be written in the given locale.

Comment: Thank you so much. Shall I need to call on all the activities and fragment?

Comment: Need to call all the activities and fragment?

Comment: onResume() is called by the system when the activity or fragment comes to the foreground. So yes, you need to call your updateResources() method in every onResume() if you need your text to be in a language different from the default language